# Pyspark to_date() function gives different answers on Windows and WSL Ubuntu

Tags: windows, datetime, pyspark, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a function that converts an int to a date which is then fed into datediff to find how many days since an event happened. One of our tests passes on PySpark Windows and in our Azure DevOps pipeline, but fails when run on PySpark in WSL Ubuntu. We've narrowed it down to the `to_date()` function producing different results on the 2 platforms, but don't understand why.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import datetime
def from_int_to_date(int_date: int) -> datetime.datetime:
    """
    Convert an integer in YYYYMMDD format into a datetime object
    """
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(str(int_date), "%Y%m%d")
```

If I calculate `F.to_date(F.lit(from_int_to_date(20190401)))` I get `Column<b"to_date(TIMESTAMP '2019-04-01 00:00:00')">` on Windows and `Column<b"to_date(TIMESTAMP('2019-03-31 23:00:00.0'))>` on the version running under WSL.

I am based in the UK and on 1 April 2019 we did our clock change for summer so I can understand the reason why it goes back an hour as the problem doesn't occur with an input int of 20190331. I'm just trying to understand why the behaviour of to_date() is different on the two systems and what we should do to mitigate for this (and any other differences) as ideally our code would be platform agnostic.

Comment: My guess is that the timezone set is UTC+0 in one system and Europe/London in the other (which is the same as UTC only during winter). It seems there is an [option `timeZone`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.options) that you can use to manually specify the timezone. (This is a comment and not an answer because I'm not 100% sure and I don't know enough about it to give an example code.) You can also try setting the environment variable `TZ`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You absolutely pointed me in the right direction. I expected the TZ to map from Windows to WSL, but apparently it's a known issue that this doesn't happen correctly. I've applied a timezone fix as suggested here https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3747 and now everything passes

Comment: Hm, thats what I just was about to write, reading the title at the bounty list.
But yes, CherryDT deserves the bounty. =)

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/856

Answer (score 0):

Set the timezone to the spark driver with the configuration `spark.sql.session.timeZone` so you won't depend on the system clock.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Europe/London")
```

This option can be settled even when the spark session is created.